# arctan of a complex number given by a relation

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $\omega$ be a complex number which satisfies
>   $$
> i \omega = \frac{u^2 -1}{u^2 +1}
> $$ for some suitable complex number $u$. Find the value of $\tan^{-1}{\omega} $

How do I solve this question? I think there is some mistake in this question.

Answer (score 0):

If $u=e^{iz}$, then $$ω=\tan(z)=\frac{\frac{u-u^{-1}}{2i}}{\frac{u+u^{-1}}2}.$$ You should be able to continue.

Comment: In order to take u as cis(theta) u should be unimodular which is not given in the question. So is this assumption correct?

Comment: No, there is not need for unimodularity as $z$ is not required to be real. Indeed $z=\arg(u)-i\ln|u|+2k\pi$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, works perfectly well.